# android click on button not hitting the event

Tags: java, android

I just have a button in my `activity_main.xml` view as below:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/capt_sig"
        android:onClick="openCaptureActivity" //click event here
        android:text="@string/capture_signature"
        android:layout_below="@+id/result"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="235dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:typeface="sans" />
```

and have below `onclick` event written in `MainActivity.java`

```
public void openCaptureActivity(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_signature);
}
```

Now `onClick` of the `button` it opens below `activity` with name `activity_capture_signature.xml` and here are the contents.

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
        android:fadeEnabled="false"
        android:gestureColor="#000"
        android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/saveSig"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:onClick="SaveSignature" //click event here
        android:text="Capture"/>
```

I have added a `onClick` for `button` as well here as you can see and the event is written in `CaptureSignatureActivity.java` as below:

```
public void SaveSignature(View v){
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Even with this setups, the `SaveSignature` event throws **FATAL EXCEPTION** as below:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   SaveSignature(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'saveSig'

I am still not able understand that even after adding `click event` in `activity`, why this exception is occurring. Is this because of the way I open the `activity` from parent? Is there anything am missing here?

Comment: Try to: Build > Clean project

Comment: Have you initialized Buttons at Activtiy.java??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start the new activity `CaptureSignatureActivity.java` in `openCaptureActivity()` method. Currently you are trying to inflate the layout inside `MainActivity` itself. Do

```
public void openCaptureActivity(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CaptureSignatureActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: Oh yea.. My understanding on this was much low.. Thanks for the timely help.. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Use different method for clicking button.for example     
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do stuff
          }
    });
```

Comment: Tried this.. But the issue was different here as mentioned in accepted answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void openCaptureActivity(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_signature);
}
```

This method does not change your activity. You are still in the `MainActivity`.
If you define click methods in xml you must define that methods in `MainActivity` or use `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void openCaptureActivity(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_signature);
}
```

see carefully  `setContentView();` this method is use to attach/set layout content to your Actiity. May be you used that method inside your `onCreate()` method also.

in your `activity_main.xml`

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/capt_sig"
        android:onClick="openCaptureActivity" //click event here
        android:text="@string/capture_signature"
        android:layout_below="@+id/result"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="235dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:typeface="sans" />
```

And then in MainActivity.java

use :

```
public void openCaptureActivity(View view){
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_signature);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,CaptureSignatureActivity.class));
}
```

now your `CaptureSignatureActivity` it should be like this

in its `onCreate()` method use this line to set content that you had used wrong in previous activity by `setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_signature);`

and then you can use second click method for button in CaptureSignatureActivity

```
public void SaveSignature(View v){
    //Do some stuff
}
```